# Sending notification using firebase Api but not receiving on the browser

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging, swagger

I am trying to send notification using firebase api in asp.net core everything is working fine on local pc but on live project the response of the function shows that the notification has been sent properly but i am not receiving any on the browser but the strange part is that when i try to send notification to the same user my retreiving the token saved in the db from firebase console i received it on the browser.
Here is the code.
Everything is working just fine it retrieves the token from db against the username and send notification to the token and result also seems fine.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendNotification(NotificationModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new ResponseModel();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ToUsername))
            {
               
                response.Message = "an error occurred while processing your request";
                response.ResponseStatus = Core.Enums.ResponseStatus.Error;
                return BadRequest(response);
            }

            var tokens =  _deviceManager.GetDeviceTokens(model.ToUsername);
            if (tokens.Any())
            {
                var result  = await NotificationsManager.SendPushNotifications(model.Message,   model.Tittle, tokens);

                response.Data = model;
                response.Message = "Success";
                response.ResponseStatus = Core.Enums.ResponseStatus.Success;


                var errorsList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Responses.Count; i++)
                {
                    var item = result.Responses[i];
                    errorsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(i.ToString(), "Success:" + item.IsSuccess + ","  + "MessageId:"+ item.MessageId + "," +"Error:"+ item.Exception));
                }
                response.ErrorsList = errorsList;

                return Ok(response);
            }
            
            response.Message = "No User found with the given username or the user you are trying to send the notification has not enabled the notification";
            response.ResponseStatus = Core.Enums.ResponseStatus.Error;
            return BadRequest(response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var response = new ResponseModel();
            response.Message = "an error occurred while processing your request" + e.Message;
            response.ResponseStatus = Core.Enums.ResponseStatus.Error;
            return BadRequest(response); throw;
        }
    }
```

This is the response i get from swagger api when i call this api:
{
"responseStatus": 200,
"errorsList": [
{
"key": "0",
"value": "Success:True,MessageId:projects/aurora-10684/messages/ff9a5a3f-def7-4120-b23f-  c9d871d25172,Error:"
}
],
"metaData": null,
"message": "Success",
"data": {
"message": "string",
"toUsername": "shahreyarbutt",
"tittle": "string"
}
}

i tried everything and everything is wokring on local but on the live project it sends the notification but fails to receive when sending from the swagger using my api but with firebase console it works fine.

Comment: no its not that its i have other API as well all of them are working

Comment: I just found out that if I log in on Edge browser it works it just isn't working on chrome when sent from swagger.

Comment: check if you have notifications enabled in chrome: settings -> privacy and security -> notifications